# Derive year from string preceded by underscores in sql postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have files like `2524DD_05_DB_25_2016_1051_RGB_RECT.tif` and `2524DD_07_2010_1051_RGB_RECT.tif`. I can use regular expressions to extract the year from the filename. How can I extract the year from the filename? The year is identified by the underscore before and after. So I am looking for the four numbers between the underscores like  `_2010_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select replace(substring(filename from '_[0-9]{4}_'), '_', '')
```